# Jquery Error in IE only

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the below and IE is telling me **'id' is null or not an object**.  Works fine in all other browsers so thinking it might be a code formatting issue in IE?  Thoughts?

```
function addZoom(region){
    $('<img />').addClass(settings.zoomClass)
        .attr({
            src: settings.blankImage,
            id: region.id
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: region.width,
            height: region.height,
            top: region.top,
            left: region.left,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }).appendTo(map).click(function(){
            //hide neighboring bullets and zoomables
            var width = settings.width;
            var height = settings.height;
            if(region.scan){
                width = region.scanwidth;
                height = region.scanheight;
            }
            $(this).siblings().fadeOut();
            $(this).hide()
                   .attr('src', region.image)
                   .fadeIn('slow')
                   .animate({
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        top: '0px',
                        left: '0px'
                    }, settings.zoomDuration, '', function(){
                        displayMap(region);
                    });
        });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is full code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27101260/map.js

The error is being thrown at `id: region.id` in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in your code is the error being thrown? Is it on `id: region.id` ? If so, it looks to me like you have an issue with your variables scope for `region`. This is something that internet explorer is notoriously picky about.

Could you post the rest of your code, in particular the bit where `region` is being assigned?

Comment: Here is full code: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27101260/map.js)

The error is being thrown at id: region.id in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing region into the `addZoom` function. You access `region.id` in `attr`. It looks like (without any additional information) that the id value is not set at this point. Have you inspected the code at runtime to see if `region` is in the correct scope (particularly whenever you call `addZoom`)?